# How to get users to see the same information while allowing other users to see another

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

i have a oracle apex registry database  which requires authentication to log in. This works fine. the table being used to authenticate users is called 'tuser' , this table has username , password and department

Three examples are as follows

```
username           password               department
x                     123                    home
y                     123                    home
z                     123                    work
```

my issue is i am using :appuser in my queries therefore when each user logs in they see their respective orders however i want the user to also see orders pertaining to their departments.

So i want **X** and **Y** to see **'home'** orders as well as their individual orders and i want **Z** to see only his order  seeing that he is from another department.

I have three tables that are linked to each other

```
 table 1- Registry         Table 2- Outgoing       table 3-Tuser

  filenuber            filenumber                    username
  filename             department                   department 
                       requestedby
```

these are just the important fields.

```
select OUTGOING.FILENUMBER as FILENUMBER,
REGISTRY.FILENAME as FILENAME,
OUTGOING.DEPARTMENT as DEPARTMENT,

from REGISTRY REGISTRY,
OUTGOING OUTGOING,
TUSER TUSER 
where REGISTRY.FILENUMBER(+) =OUTGOING.FILENUMBER
and OUTGOING.DEPARTMENT(+) =TUSER.department
and outgoing.requestby (+) = TUSER.username
```

this is what i have tried but all users sees the data. if i add

```
select OUTGOING.FILENUMBER as FILENUMBER,
REGISTRY.FILENAME as FILENAME,
OUTGOING.DEPARTMENT as DEPARTMENT,

from REGISTRY REGISTRY,
OUTGOING OUTGOING,
TUSER TUSER 
where REGISTRY.FILENUMBER(+) =OUTGOING.FILENUMBER
and OUTGOING.DEPARTMENT(+) =TUSER.department
and outgoing.requestby (+) = TUSER.username
AND outgoing.Department  =:APP_USER
```

this will mean that  because  **x** made a request and y didnt only **x** will see his request even though **y** is in the same department.

What i will like to get is when **X** makes a request **Y** must see it even though **Y** didnt make that request and this is because **Y** is in the same department

Answer (score 0):

Would this be OK? In Apex, line #20 would be `where u.username = :APP_USER;` (this is SQL*Plus example).

```
SQL> with
  2  tuser (username, department) as
  3    (select 'x', 'home' from dual union all
  4     select 'y', 'home' from dual union all
  5     select 'z', 'work' from dual
  6    ),
  7  registry (filenumber, filename) as
  8    (select 100, 'file 1' from dual union all
  9     select 200, 'file 2' from dual
 10    ),
 11  outgoing (filenumber, department, requestedby) as
 12    (select 100, 'home', 'x' from dual union all
 13     select 200, 'work', 'z' from dual
 14    )
 15  select r.filenumber,
 16         r.filename,
 17         o.requestedby
 18  from registry r join outgoing o on o.filenumber = r.filenumber
 19                  join tuser u on u.department = o.department
 20  where u.username = '&APP_USER';
Enter value for app_user: x

FILENUMBER FILENA R
---------- ------ -
       100 file 1 x

SQL> /
Enter value for app_user: y

FILENUMBER FILENA R
---------- ------ -
       100 file 1 x

SQL> /
Enter value for app_user: z

FILENUMBER FILENA R
---------- ------ -
       200 file 2 z

SQL>
```